# Show in the email from which page the form was submitted

Tags: php, wordpress, email, post, superglobals

I have a html form on every page and I need to be able to show in the receiver email from which page the visitor submitted the form. How can I achieve this in PHP? I have tried using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` whatsoever, but it just simply doesn't output anything. I'm using Wordpress.

```
<?php
  global $post;
  $post_slug=$post->post_name;
  $name = $_POST['firstname'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message="$name.$email";
    mail('example@gmail.com', "Hello", "$name \n $email \n $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']");
    echo "works";
?>
```

Comment: Are you posting the data to the different url or is it self referencing form. If a new url you can try $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

Comment: I’m posting to email.php, so it’s different url, not the same page where the form sits.

Comment: Please use $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] and check if it works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine except, you should enclose array variables inside strings with curled braces {}:

```
mail('example@gmail.com', "Hello", "$name \n $email \n {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
```

If you check the official php documentation on: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing you can see in section "Complex (curly) syntax":

```
// Works, quoted keys only work using the curly brace syntax
echo "This works: {$arr['key']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the actual url with :

```
$actual_link = "http(s)://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something this . Pass the title of your page ( or the permalink ) to a hidden html input and  take the values as :

```
 $titlePage = get_the_title($post->ID);

 <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $titlePage; ?>" name="pagetitle">
```

Then in your  email code :

```
 $pagetitle = $_POST['pagetitle'];
```

Now you have your parameter, use it in your email like you want.